# "Administrator", "DefaultAccount", "Guest": Can I remove these accounts?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, administrator, guest-account

Can I safely delete any/all of these accounts, or will that break Windows 10 Home?

```
Administrator
DefaultAccount
Guest
```

I see lots of posts on *how* to delete system accounts, but I'm surprised I can't find any definitive answers as to whether Windows absolutely *needs* all three accounts.

*EDIT:

This mission started when I was trying to change permissions/ownership on some files, but the Permissions (and sharing) boxes were showing SID's instead of Names.  I'm not sure when this started.  Thus, I began research I found posts suggesting to add-then-remove a new user and that would fix the names, however it had no effect.

I eventually got the FullNames showing instead of SID.  Perhaps my trial and error was getting out of hand but I then realized the only remaining issue is that MY account (linked to @hotmail) was still missing FullName.  I confirmed that it exists in my Microsoft.

Still learning `wmic` context, I entered something like:
`wmic useraccount set fullname="mynewname"'

I was *aware* that this didn't specify which account to name but I mistakenly assumed that it would either rename only the current account, or else throw an error, maybe a warning.  Nope.  All accounts renamed.  *sigh*

After a frustrated hour of googling and experimenting with context, I *finally* got everything set like it was supposed to be.  (Thankfully I had a list from before my mistake.)

**REBOOT** - **changes gone**.  SID showing for all accounts *except* my son's @gmail-linked account - which is fine (perhaps only since he hasn't logged in yet?).

Changed them again, reboot, **reverted**.

Do I need to "commit" these changes somehow?  What, at login, is confusing the user list?

Which brings me back to my original question -- No, the disabled accounts do not show on the login screen, but they do show in the permissions lists (with more control than me by default), and `wmic` tells me that Default & Guest do not require a password.

I was concerned that, even if an account isn't listed on the login screen, that it could still connect to the machine remotely (and with no password?)

Thanks for your patience; I'm obviously pretty green about some of this stuff, and got really frustrated with this, what appeared to be a pretty darn straightforward fix.

[image: Useraccounts]

Comment: It is not possible to delete the Administrator account.  By default the account is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing administrator and guest account is not possible, however you can disable these accounts if there available on the logon screen.

You can use the following command to disable them.
For disabling admin account:
`Net user administrator /active:no`

For disabling the guest account:
`Net user guest /active:no`

Comment: Worth pointing out that both of the built-in accounts in question are disabled by default.  Additionally, the `DefaultAccount`isn't typically logged into (I don't even think it can be logged into) it's a profile used to template all other users.

Comment: @user787380 thank you for the tip -- the accounts are not showing on login screen, but much more annoyingly, they show in permissions and sharing dialogs, and without a name - just the SID.  I see other posts with solutions, but none of them seem to working for me.

Comment: Is the `defaultAccount` the same as the `SYSTEM` account?