# Why do I have a Roaming Profile? (Windows 7 & 10 HOME Editions)

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, user-accounts, roaming-profiles, appdata

I'm a little confused why it's looks like roaming profiles are enabled, but they are not.

Profile Status in 'User Profiles' and WMIC say "Local", yet there's a `Roaming` folder (aka `%appdata%`) housing a third of my appdata.

Here is an image of the User Profiles screen and a list of profiles folders:

[image: User Profiles]

This is on two laptops (Windows 7 Home & Windows 10 Home), both recently formatted.  There's no workgroup or file sharing between them.  Could it be because I used the same @hotmail Microsoft Account when creating Users on both computers?  Is there any advantage to splitting up my data like this?

Googling for an answer shows me how to add/remove roaming profiles, but not about data being stored there when I haven't instructed Windows to do so.

An explanation or links to related reading would be appreciated... Thanks!

***EDIT:**
Mis-capitalized one folder name.

[image: Corrected File List]

thanks for the simple link -- I was overthinking, thinking "Roaming" must have already "Roamed" somewhere, as opposed to organizing data in case of "future roaming!"

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/318177/what-is-the-appdata-folder-in-windows/

Comment: The article posted by @Appleoddity provides a thorough explanation.  These folders have existed within Windows builds for more than a decade.

Comment: All users accounts have those three folders.  There is nothing abnormal about those folders existing.

Comment: The author's image is obviously incorrect.  The folder name is `FolderLow` not `LocAllow` or `localAllow`.

Comment: Folder name was a manual typo.  Should be `LocalLow`  (spelled the same as LocAllow, just capitalized differently.)

Comment: @Appleoddity i'd upvote your comment or make an accepted answer...  but I'm too new!     ...How come all answers can't be that easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You don't have a roaming profile***, otherwise, the profile type (from your first image) would read 'Roaming'.

The 3 folders in appdata are Local, LocalLow and Roaming.

The roaming folder is for data that SHOULD roam with the user data, if such a profile is enabled.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766489(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I get that now.   Now if I could figure out how to get the Names showing again instead of SSID's, I'd be golden.  (Bottom image [here](https://superuser.com/q/1261565/774713))